# Getting an element from array

Tags: php, arrays

when i run this code;

```
print_r($response);
```

i got this result;

```
Array ( 
    [SaleWithTicketResult] => Array ( 
                [TicketObjectId] => 097d403b-102f-4274-9915- 11060c20c23a
                [TransactionDate] => 2014-08-20T13:25:50.3008477+03:00
                [StatusCode] => 0 
                [RedirectUrl] => http://www.mikrom-odeme.com/sale-api/tr/ticket.aspx?id=097d403b-102f-42994-9915-11060c20c23a 
    ) 
)
```

But i want to get only RedirectUrl from this array result.

How can i get only RedirectUrl from this array.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `$redirectUrl = $response['SaleWithTicketResult']['RedirectUrl']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

echo $response['SaleWithTicketResult']['RedirectUrl'];
Since its a two dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $response['SaleWithTicketResult']['RedirectUrl'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

You should use index with array variable to get it from multidimensional array.

```
<?php echo $response['SaleWithTicketResult']['RedirectUrl']; ?>
```

You can get more about the same from **[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)**